# How to calculate scalar product of two gradients in indicial notation?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-products

Does someone knows how calculate scalar product of two gradients and put the result in terms of nabla operator? .

$(\vec\nabla{\gamma})\cdot(\vec\nabla{\gamma})$ = ?

Comment: Cross-posted to http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/130127/2451

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, the differential operator doesn't commute with functions. It is unreasonable to write $\partial_i\gamma\partial_i\gamma=\partial_i\partial_i\gamma\gamma$.

A common way to write this
$$\delta^{ij}\partial_i\gamma\partial_j\gamma=\partial^j\gamma\partial_j\gamma$$